# How can i turn home gas from liquid to gas

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation

I hope i am not too off topic, couldn't find a more suitable stack-exchange forum for this, if there is a better one, please point me to it,

Well my question is the following,

I am working on a personal project, i have a gas balloon (Liquefied petroleum gas) with a pressure of 4-5 bar, i need some kind of a device/filter that would convert it to gas (instead of liquid) with a small pressure, i used an industrial vaporizer, but it gave me something stronger than i need, and "not clean",

Basically, what i need is to build a very big lither, 
like this:

[image: as you can see, just gas, and wick that turns to a "clean" fire]

As you can see, just gas, and wick that turns to a "clean" fire, without all the side effects that the vaporizer creates,

Now, i am missing a lot of knowledge here, and i would like to know if someone can guide me to how should i do this, what are the names and definitions for the stuff i need etc,
Any knowledge regarding to what i should do, or how, or where can i find it will be mostly appreciated.

EDIT:

When i used the phrase "home gas" which is common in my state, i meant Liquefied petroleum gas (LPG).

Here is the vaporizer i used now (it belongs to someone who knows what he is doing, i do not plan on killing myself :)

[image]

So, ill try to re-describe my problem,

I want to get "clean slow flame" such as a lighter has, what i am getting, regardless to the vaporizer pressure, feels like its not clean, as if some gas is not really burning and its just comes out as well, or something in the proccess makes it dirtier.

Comment: A lighter works because liquids in closed containers are continuously evaporating into gas and condensing back into liquid until the [equilibrium vapor pressure](http://www.chem.purdue.edu/gchelp/liquids/vpress.html) is reached. When you open the container the vapor rushes out (because the pressure inside is higher than the air pressure outside) and the escaping gas can be ignited. The equilibrium vapor pressure depends on the temperature of the liquid.

Comment: This sounds **very** dangerous.

Comment: You seem to have asked the same question on the chemistry site http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/28717/

Comment: _"..it belongs to someone who knows what he is doing, i do not plan on killing myself"_ - Killing yourself is not the worse that could happen. You could instead kill someone else by accident. Or cause serious injuries that could last for life. On top of that you would end up in jail. I cant tell what exactly you are trying to do, or if it really is as dangerous as it sounds, but you might want to think twice. Also, your friend may "know what he is doing" but on the other hand, he might not really know.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is potentially very dangerous - but it is also what happens inside many cars in the [carburetor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carburetor) - this is really an engineering / chemical engineering problem and if you are serious about doing this you might want to look up the linked wikipedia page about carburetors. Hope this is useful

edit - after useful comment elsewhere - carburetor will premix fuel and air so make a potentially explosive mixture - better just to have a valve where you can regulate the flow of gas above you 'home gas' - this gas would be best burnt with a proper burner that is appropriate for the type of gas you have.